# Loop through object and map to value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to loop through an object literal and map the substring to a value and plug it into an equation. Right now my code doesn't return an integer but instead is undefined. Here is the code:

```
function calcFunc(sequence) {
    var dH = 0;
    var dS = 108;
    var i;
    // Compute dH and dS
    for ( i = 0 ; i < ( sequence.length - 1 ) ; i++ ) {
        var pair = sequence.substr(i, 2);
        dH += nn_h[pair];
        dS += nn_s[pair];
    }
    dH *= -100.0;
    dS *= -0.1;
    return dH / ( dS + 1.987 * Math.log( 100 / 4000000000.0 ) ) - 273.15 +
    16.6 * ( Math.log( 50 / 1000.0 ) / Math.log(10) );   
}
```

Comment: Could you add a fiddle example ?

Comment: what is sequence in your calcFunc ?

Comment: example function call would be as follows: var sequence = "tctgtt"; calcFunc(sequence)

Comment: `/ log(10)` should be `/ Math.log(10)`?

Comment: Without knowing what your `sequence` looks like, could it be that you should increase `i` by 2 in your loop?

Comment: What Nina said. When I try to run it I get the error that log is not defined. Of course when fixing that I get a result of NaN but the sequence I pass in might be wrong.

Comment: As i tried so far instead of returns _undefined_ it returns **NaN** [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0pnooxde/)

Comment: I suppose _sequence_ its a string, because you are using _String.prototype.substr_ method.

Comment: please supply `sequence`

Comment: example sequence could be 'tctgtt'

Comment: @Haloor in this case you will get **NaN**

Comment: @Haloor, there are some more values missing. at least `nn_s` should have the same keys as `nn_h`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there are at least two errors:

1. Trying to call log(10) instead of Math.log(10). This is likely causing the undefined error.
2. Not converting the strings to integers when you load them from the `nn_s` and `nn_h` objects. This means you will concatenate the strings rather than add them together as integers.

   ```
   function calcFunc(sequence) {
       var dH = 0;
       var dS = 108;
       var i;

       // Compute dH and dS
       for ( i = 0 ; i < ( sequence.length - 1 ) ; i++ ) {
           var pair = sequence.substr(i, 2);
           dH += parseInt(nn_h[pair], 10); // parseInt
           dS += parseInt(nn_s[pair], 10); // parseInt
       }

       dH *= -100.0;
       dS *= -0.1;

       return dH / ( dS + 1.987 * Math.log( 100 / 4000000000.0 ) ) - 273.15 +
           16.6 * ( Math.log( 50 / 1000.0 ) / Math.log(10) );   // Math.log(10)
   }
   ```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/015zp47y/1/)

Comment: Im fairly sure the third problem is not increasing the `i` by 2. Otherwise for the input specified (`tctgtt`) there is a value for `tc` but not one for `ct`

Comment: @Jamiec Possibly, that depends on the possible sequence values.

Answer (score 0):

As I stated:

- `Math.log()` is missing
- Values are not numbers
- Increment should be 2
- Some keys and values are missing (here filled with `0`)

The missing values can be replaced by a default value like

```
dH += nn_h[pair] || 0;
dS += nn_s[pair] || 0;
```

```js
var nn_s = {
    tc: 135,
    tg: 129,
    tt: 240,
    tn: 168,
    na: 168,
    nc: 210,
    ng: 220,
    nt: 215,
    nn: 203
};
var nn_h = {
    tc: 0,
    tg: 0,
    tt: 0,
    tn: 66,
    na: 66,
    nc: 85,
    ng: 91,
    nt: 80,
    nn: 80
};
function calcFunc(sequence) {
    var dH = 0;
    var dS = 108;
    var i;
    // Compute dH and dS
    for (i = 0 ; i < sequence.length ; i+=2) {
        var pair = sequence.substr(i, 2);
        dH += nn_h[pair];
        dS += nn_s[pair];
    }
    dH *= -100.0;
    dS *= -0.1;
    return dH / (dS + 1.987 * Math.log(100 / 4000000000.0)) - 273.15 +
    16.6 * (Math.log(50 / 1000.0) / Math.log(10));
}

document.write(calcFunc('tctgtt'));
```